# in python, how I get the value of the fifth line value , not the second line

Tags: python

in website I have this source code

```
            <div class="estimated-delivery">
<input id="currentCity" type="hidden" value="City">
<input id="currentCityISO" type="hidden" value="CY">
<input id="idUnit" type="hidden" value="3910200523">
<input id="availableOffers" type="hidden" value="4">
```

and I wrote this in python

```
lastvalue = page_soup.find("div", {"class": "estimated-delivery"})
lastvalue.input["value"]
```

the result came back

```
'City'
```

I do not need the first value in the second line of website source code ,
I need the value of the fifth line in the website source code which is

```
'4'
```

Thanks

Comment: what should I change in my python code ?

Comment: You never selected `availableOffers`, so why should it give you the fifth value?

Comment: do you need just the fifth line strictly, or is it the value of "availableOffers" that you're interested in?

Comment: value of "availableOffers" that I am  interested in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point I was trying to make in a comment to zerecees answer earlier, was that given the HTML.

```
<div class="estimated-delivery">
   <input id="currentCity" type="hidden" value="City">
   <input id="currentCityISO" type="hidden" value="CY">
   <input id="idUnit" type="hidden" value="3910200523">
   <input id="availableOffers" type="hidden" value="4">
<div>
```

You can first locate the div container, and then search the div for input elements with a specific id.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page_soup= BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')
div=page_soup.find("div", {"class": "estimated-delivery"})
inp_val=div.find("input", {"id": "availableOffers"})["value"]
```

Or if you are not sure about the id's of the input elements, and you want to get  the value of the 4th input element (index 3) you can use find_all and do something like this.

```
inp_val=div.find_all("input")[3]["value"]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would find this option much easier:

```py
last_value = soup.find("input", {"id": "availableOffers"})["value"]
```

Full example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = r"""<div class="estimated-delivery">
<input id="currentCity" type="hidden" value="City"></input>
<input id="availableOffers" type="hidden" value="4"></input>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')
soup.find("input", {"id": "availableOffers"})["value"]

>>> '4'
```

Comment: I haven't really used beautiful soup, but cant you chain them to first find the div, and then 'find_all("input", {"id": "availableOffers"})' of that div?

Comment: I believe you are right - I am no beautiful soup expert either, though. However, OP seems new, so I was trying to space things out a little to avoid too much in one line. Do you have an edit? If you recommend one, I'll accept it.

Comment: OP attempted to comment back in an edit saying code didn't work. OP, which code we're you saying didn't work?

Comment: Edited for clarity. What language do you speak? Maybe I can speak your native language and assist better.